# Problema con etiqueta <link> en html

Tags: html, laravel, ubuntu

tengo un proyecto en laravel en un servidor ubuntu en aws, pero los links a las hojas de estilo css no funcionan
Esta es la ruta: **/var/www/html/assets/css/leadmark.css**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté poner la ruta de ambas maneras:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero ninguna funciona, mi pagina sigue sin mostrar el css    (Ambos links estan adentro de las etiquetas `<head>`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la consola del navegador que te aparece ?? Cuál es la url de la última foto?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Has eliminado de la barra de direcciones lo más importante: la localización del archivo HTML. Las rutas relativas dependen de dónde esté localizado éste. ¿Podrías indicarlo en la pregunta? Gracias. Además, recuerda que para indicar una ruta absoluta en un sistema de archivos local, la URL debe tener el esquema `file:`.

Comment: Acabo de fijarme que estás usando Laravel. ¿Qué versión de Laravel estás usando? ¿Usas Laravel Mix? ¿Has probado `{{ asset('assets/css/leadmark.css') }}`?

Comment: @OscarGarcia laravel 9.x, intenté {{ asset('assets/css/leadmark.css') }} pero tampoco funciona

Comment: @OscarGarcia el archivo html se encuentra en /var/www/html/resources/views

Comment: @Yussef http://angelhernandez.work/assets/imgs/avatar-2.jpg

Comment: Necesitaría ver el contenido del `.htaccess` para ver si hay alguna regla de redirección está alterando los resultados.

Comment: @OscarGarcia puse el contenido en la publicación arriba

Comment: @AngelHernadez, agradecería mucho que el código lo copiaras/pegaras en vez de usar para todo capturas de pantalla. Eso no nos facilita nada probar diferentes configuraciones. Por otro lado, estoy viendo que el directorio donde está el `.htaccess` se llama `public`, y sin embargo en el árbol de directorios que mostraste ese directorio no existe. ¿Es tu directorio local?

Comment: Y los permisos de carpeta, los revisaste?

Comment: Hay un directorio que se llama var/www/html/ y adentro están los directorios README.md
app
artisan
assets
bootstrap
composer.json
composer.lock
config
------public--------- aqui está el .htaccess
database
lang
package.json
phpunit.xml
public
resources
routes
storage
tests
vendor
vite.config.js